# Swift dynamic function call from Any

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make a generic testing interface that takes an  function, fills out the function signature parameters via introspection, and then runs the arbitrary function.

```
Test(function: <Any>)
{
    let signature = Mirror(reflecting:function)
    ...
}
```

In Swift 3 I can get the function signature from reflection. With the Zewo library I have KVO & KVC built on top of the swift 3 Metadata. So far so good.

But the last two steps I'm tripping over: Building up a arbitrary parameter list and dynamically calling Function.

Is there a generic way to do this? (pointers are allowed!) Now that tuple splat is gone (and it was never dynamic in the first place), are there any exposed methods for dynamic arguments, or popping arguments onto the stack dynamically or another language provision?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is not possible.

Comment: I would have said the same thing until I saw Zewo's very clean implementation of KVO and KVC using swift pointers

Comment: Do you have a link to that Zewo thing? I've done a simple [KVC implementation](https://github.com/NozeIO/Noze.io/blob/master/Sources/mustache/SimpleKVC.swift) too, and I'm pretty sure this is not possible today ;->

Comment: Not sure it'll help you, but as long as you call global functions that happen to match the C ABI (basic ones seem to do), you could use libffi to create the call. You may be able to construct arbitrary calls if you do the ARC by hand and follow the Swift ABI, but urghhh.

Comment: Heres the dynamic reflection API from zewo: https://github.com/Zewo/Reflection

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking if I has to I could use Dyncall.org to dynamically call functions from C, wrap a clean API with Swift. Swift->C->Swift. Yuck, but could work

Comment: Well, isn't it so that Swift functions you call from C must be @convention(C) convertible? If so (and if this is OK for your use case), you could also mark your Swift functions [like that](https://github.com/AlwaysRightInstitute/mod_swift/blob/master/mods_baredemo/Sources/mods_baredemo.swift#L85) and call them via libffi (or dyncall, which I suppose is similar). (ps the Zewo stuff looks awfully complicated, can it do more than the simple Mirror based reflection for properties or is it just for speed?)

Comment: It can be used for dynamic creation of types, and and retrieval of object data by name. Yeah the convertible is a limitation.